# Minimal distance between coprimes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

For a natural number $K$, I want to choose $n$ pairwise coprime numbers all of which are bigger than $K$ such that the distance $d$ between the smallest and the largest one is minimal.

For example, for any $K$ if $n=2$ we get $d=1$.

Similarly for any $K$ if $n=3$ then $d=2$.

I need a formula for such $d$ depending on $K$ and $n$. I do not need to know what those coprime numbers are.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the relevance of $K$?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. All coprimes are bigger than $K$.

Comment: If $n=3$ then $d=2$ regardless if there are infinitely many twin primes.

Comment: Oh thanks, sorry.

Comment: Just to make it clear why: if n is any integer, then $2n+1, 2n+2$ and $2n+3$ are pairwise relatively prime.

Comment: The Polymath8 project to find narrow gaps between primes investigated "admissible tuples" at some length. This is closely related to your question - some bounds were found, but not an exact formula. Someone else may be able to give a better exposition and link. See e.g. http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes

Answer (score 4):

A short observation: $d$ only depends on $n$.

Indeed, if you can find some integers $k_1,..,k_n$ like in the problem for some $K$, then for all $m$ the numbers $(\prod (k_j-k_i))^m+k_i$ are also integers like in the problem.

Indeed if $d| (\prod (k_j-k_i))^m+k_l$ and $d|(\prod (k_j-k_i))+k_s$ then, by taking the difference $d| k_l-k_s$ and hence $d| \prod (k_j-k_i)$. It follows that $d| gcd(k_l, k_s)=1$.

Now, by picking $m$ large enough, you can create numbers as large as you want.

So the question is actually equivalent to the following: For each $n$, which is the smallest possible difference between the largest and smallest numbers among $n$ coprime numbers?

It is clear that $d \leq p_{n-1}$, but this is an upperbound which can probably be improved.